# PayPal Express Checkout displaying different templates

Tags: php, templates, paypal, express-checkout

I'm using paypal express checkout and have ran into an issue with different templates being displayed. When you enter this link https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-8MC80852TL566402R# the new paypal checkout template appears. When I use this link which was created from the paypal playground Java demo https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-7SG06046NN311382F the old template is render. I examined both links and they have the same format.

Does paypal have a specific url format in order to render the new template?

Answer (score 0):

The checkout page layout is determined by the PayPal System(IP address,location etc).The new layout is being rolled out to all the merchant across countries.

Comment: how do I force the new layout? The old one is not mobile friendly.